# How to run ReactJS app on Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I created a Azure function and deployed my build ReactJS app on it:

[image]

I can find all the files in my `/wwwroot` folder:

[image]

When I visit the URL I see:

[image]

What do I need to do to run my React app on Azure Function?

Answer (score 7):

I guess your goal is to run a static website in a serverless way.  While it is possible to [serve files from Functions](https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-static-file-server/), a better way is to store the website files in Blob Storage [static website hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website).  A reference architecture is available [from Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/serverless/web-app).

[image: Reference architecture]

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpND9qVc3qo) explains how to create a pipeline to deploy your files to Blob Storage.

You can then use Functions as a [proxy to the files in Storage](https://markheath.net/post/static-websites-azure-blob-storage-functions-proxies).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Quick question though. I don't want to run a static website, I want to run a ReactJS app which needs NodeJS. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: Well, React does not require Node. You need a backend?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma "static website" in this context refers to hosting the static files necessary for the browser to run a ReactJS app (your webpack bundle and an `index.html`, for instance). If you don't need a custom NodeJS backend, you should host the static files in blob storage as @csharprocks suggests (per MS guidelines) and use AZ functions to host your API, which your ReactJS front end will call. If you are using SSR, or need a custom NodeJS backend (using Express for instance), you should use an App Service rather than AZ Functions.